# Designing Discrete differential inputs Amplifier

Tags: transistors

I am trying to analyse a discrete differential amplifier circuit by answering some question. I have done the analysis of the input stage, I would appreciate if I can get some feedback on my approach.
[image]

Here is my approach for the input stage

[image]

---

Here is the other part of the differential amplifier
[image]
[image]

---

Here are the calculations for the input stage
[image]
[image]

Comment: and your question is? Note that in going from A to B+C, you have not only lost the vital emitter to emitter connection, but also the concept that that R135 is a single device sourcing a current into the emitters. You say that you 'have done the analysis of the input stage'. I have looked through your post twice and still not found any text that suggests that.

Comment: I just added the calculations I have done

Comment: Your analysis will never be right if you want perfection. Any assumptions made will degrade the math away from the reality and imperfections in the true components. This makes it unrealistic to expect someone to do any checking because you have not stated your assumptions about what models you are considering. Sure, anyone could laboriously wade through your calcs (posted as answers) and try and figure out what assumptions you have made but that seems unlikely. I'm voting to close this question on it's unsuitability.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach misses what's going on, and over-concentrates on minutiae. Basically you can't see the wood for the trees.

A better approach would be to say

a) assuming inputs are roughly at ground potential

b) then means roughly 24v is across R135 (ignore 0.7v in comparison to 24v), so about 200uA is flowing in R135

c) which for equal base voltages will split 100uA to each transistor.

That's enough accuracy for the bias conditions, any more polishing is superfluous, and shows you don't understand what is important.

Next, we have to figure out what the *gain* of this emitter coupled pair is. You haven't done that yet.

d) The input voltage, the difference between the base voltages, acts to drive a current through the effective emitter resistances. What are they? The slope of the base-emitter diode voltage for base current gives the effective resistance. As a rule of thumb, it's around 25ohms for a room temperature silicon diode at 1mA, and scales inversely with bias current. So with junctions conducting 100uA, and two in series, it's around 500 ohms.

e) That signal current flows through the collector resistor R117, with value 15k. Therefore the voltage gain of this stage is 15k/500, which is about 30x.

f) now you have to analyse the pair that's the 'other way up'. When you finally add the results together in the output stage, you'll find that the 'input voltage around 0v' assumption wasn't as necessary as first thought!

You'll notice I haven't used Vbe, but assumed it's *small*, and haven't used hFE, assumed it's *big*, at least compared to the calculated gain of 30x. Neither are needed to get the bias conditions *and the gain* well within the ballpark.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41643/discussion-on-answer-by-neil-uk-designing-discrete-differential-inputs-amplifier).